# Using the MATCH function inside IF statement in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, function

I think this is probably an easy one but it's got me.  I am trying to create a user defined function (my first) that will look to match the value of a specific cell to a range on other sheets of the same workbook.  Then based on if a match occurs, it will return a string for the cell based on which range it was found.

```
Function DxLookup(Cell As Range) As String

If WorksheetFunction.Match(Cell.Value, Sheet2.Range("A:A"), 0) Then
DxLookup = "Unspecified"
ElseIf WorksheetFunction.Match(Cell.Value, Sheet3.Range("A:A"), 0) Then
DxLookup = "Invalid"
End If

End Function
```

As a simple example, I would apply this function to Cell B1 `=DxLookup(A1)`
What I would like it to do is take the value in A1, look for a match in Sheet2 Column A, and if it finds a match, return "Unspecified" in Cell B1.  If it doesn't find a match, it then looks in Sheet3 Column A to find a match, the return "Invaild" if a match is found.

The issue that I am running into when running this function, is if it comes back true on the first condition, it will indeed return "Unspecified".  However, if it doesn't it seems like it isn't trying the second condition for "Invalid" and returns #VALUE! for the cell.

Any help of tips would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `WorksheetFunction.Match()` will throw a runtime error if there's no match.  You can instead test for `If IsError(Application.Match)` which will be True if there's no match.

Comment: Thanks Tim, I think that it is getting me close.  Issue is it is giving me a return of "Unspecified" if the value is not found in column of A of Sheet2.  I am needing to return "Unspecified" if it does find a match.  I hope that makes sense?

Comment: Thanks, I got it figured out with your tip.  Only adjustment I made was I added NOT before IsError to reverse the logic.  Thanks again!